# Display data from database in datatable

Tags: laravel, datatable

I have a table "karyawans" which contains 104 data and i want to display it all in a datatable. i have done all manual from datatable and here is the result

![datatable result][1]

here is my data

![my data][2]

here is the view

```
    @extends('layout.main')
    @section('container')
      <!-- page content -->
      <div class="right_col" role="main">
        <div class="">
          <div class="page-title">
            <div class="title_left">
              <h3><small>Daftar karyawan yang telah ditambahkan</small></h3>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Karyawan <small>Users</small></h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
                        aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings 1</a>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <div class="card-box table-responsive">
                        <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                          style="width:100%">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>NIK</th>
                              <th>Nama</th>
                              <th>Username</th>
                              <th>Email</th>
                              <th>Unit</th>
                              <th>Jabatan</th>
                              <th></th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            @foreach ($karyawans as $karyawan)
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{ $karyawan->nik }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $karyawan->nama }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $karyawan->username }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $karyawan->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $karyawan->unit }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $karyawan->jabatan }}</td>
                                <td>
                                  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"> Ubah</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"> Hapus</a>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            @endforeach
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endsection
```

and here is where I store the css and js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('images/rs.png') }}" type="image/png" />

  <title>Sistem Manajemen Pekerjaan </title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- NProgress -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../vendors/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
  <link
    href="{{ asset('../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/css/bootstrap-progressbar-3.3.4.min.css') }}"
    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jqvmap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css') }}"
    type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
  <link href="{{ asset('../build/css/custom.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{{ asset('//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}">
  {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="{{ asset('https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.11.3/af-2.3.7/b-2.0.1/cr-1.5.5/date-1.1.1/fc-4.0.1/fh-3.2.0/kt-2.6.4/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.4/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.5/sb-1.3.0/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.css') }}"> --}}



</head>

<body class="nav-md">
  <div class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">
      @include('partial.nav_bar')

      <!-- top navigation -->
      @include('partial.top_nav')
      <!-- /top navigation -->

      <!-- page content -->
      <div class="container">
        @yield('container')
      </div>
      <!-- /page content -->

      <!-- footer content -->
      @include('partial.footer')
      <!-- /footer content -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}">
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- FastClick -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js') }}">
  </script>
  <!-- NProgress -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- Chart.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/Chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js') }}">
  </script>
  <!-- gauge.js -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js') }}">
  </script>
  <!-- bootstrap-progressbar -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/bootstrap-progressbar/bootstrap-progressbar.min.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/iCheck/icheck.min.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- Skycons -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/skycons/skycons.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- Flot -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.pie.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.time.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.stack.js') }}">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/Flot/jquery.flot.resize.js') }}">
  </script>
  <!-- Flot plugins -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/flot.orderbars/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/flot-spline/js/jquery.flot.spline.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/flot.curvedlines/curvedLines.js') }}">
  </script>
  <!-- DateJS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/DateJS/build/date.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- JQVMap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/jqvmap/dist/jquery.vmap.js') }}">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/jqvmap/dist/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/jqvmap/examples/js/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../vendors/moment/min/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('../vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js') }}"></script>

  <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('../build/js/custom.min.js') }}"></script>

  <!-- dataTables -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ asset('//cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datatable').DataTable();
    });
  </script>

  {{-- <script type="text/javascript"
    src="{{ assset('https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.11.3/af-2.3.7/b-2.0.1/cr-1.5.5/date-1.1.1/fc-4.0.1/fh-3.2.0/kt-2.6.4/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.4/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.5/sb-1.3.0/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.js') }}">
  </script> --}}

</body>

</html>
```

here is the KaryawanController

```
    public function daftar_karyawan()
        {
            return view('karyawans', [
                "karyawans" => Karyawan::first()->filter(request(['cari']))->orderBy('id', 'asc')
                ->paginate(10)->withQueryString()
            ]);
        }
```

FYI, I try to use the manual paginaton and searching before i know the 'datatables'

and this is the route

```
    Route::get('/daftar_karyawan', [KaryawanController::class, 'daftar_karyawan']);
``

Sorry if there is an mistake in writing my question, because I am new to this forum and this is my first question, thank you


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGQID.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2X22.png
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by you `want to display it all in a datatable`? Your screenshot shows that the data is indeed being displayed in a data table.  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Do you want to show 104 rows in your table?

Comment: @fufubrocat i have edited my post, there is the pict of my data

Comment: @A.ANoman yes sir

Comment: @FebryanAkhdani can you show us your controller? Seems like you're using `->paginate();` for your `$karyawans` variable instead of `->get();`

Comment: @FebryanAkhdani, Please show your controller code where you fetch your data

Comment: @fufubrocat there is the KaryawanControler

Comment: @FebryanAkhdani What is the value of `$request->cari`?

Comment: @fufubrocat it's a code for search manually. like what i just say in my edited post, I using a manually search and pagination before. So the value its nothing, i guess (hehe)

Comment: @FebryanAkhdani then perhaps you can try this in your controller? `$karyawans = Karyawan::all();` then edit your return view to `return view('karyawans', compact('karyawans'));`

Comment: @fufubrocat it's work.... Thank You so much

Comment: @FebryanAkhdani That's great. Appreciate it if you can upvote my comment with the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove **Paginate(10)** and replace with **get()** in **KaryawanController**

```
public function daftar_karyawan()
{
    return view('karyawans', [
        "karyawans" => Karyawan::first()->filter(request(['cari']))->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->get()
    ]);
}
```

You can't use **Paginate()** for the datatable because it will limit to 10 :)
Just use get() and datatable will auto paginate !

ps:
If retrieving more than 1000 rows then there is a high chances system will load slow. Recommended to use AJAX to prevent this issue :)